# How to send/receive text between Android and Computer?

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, nfc

I want to send a plain or rich text from/to Android <-> Computer, probably to clipboard but not necessarily. How can I do that? I don't want to email or create a file in order write text into it.

Does the Android API allow to do that somehow? Maybe via NFC or Bluetooth?

I'd like it to be wireless.

Comment: You can use NetworkSocket for that.

Comment: check for [socket](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html)

Comment: @Mohit, isn't that between two Android devices?

Answer (score 1):

From your android device you can pass String to PC like this .

```
try {
    Socket socket = new Socket(DESTINATION_ADDRESS, DESTINATION_PORT);
    // Exmp : Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.101", 80);
    OutputStream outToServer = socket.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
    out.writeUTF(SEND_STRING); 
    // Exmp : out.writeUTF("TEST");
    socket.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And from PC you have to receive the message and do action .

```
try {
    InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1000);

} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Run an infinite loop to check if the message is received or not.
while (true) {
        try {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String message = in.readUTF(); // Get the message which send from android device. 

            /* do other staff after getting the message . */
        }atch (Exception ex) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: you can connect by wire , or you can use Wifi to do this . You need to connected under same network . "By how!" is now important .

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for, I want to do it via NFC, bluetooth or any wireless means. wifi won't work for me.