# Basic Android chat app starter with Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, chat

I want to create a chat app for my school, but I don't know where to start from. I found one from [Android Chat Starter](https://github.com/DeromirNeves/whatsapp-android) but it uses `listview` for showing the conversations, which I am finding difficult to apply to Recyclerview.

Comment: Could you please give details of the difficulties you are finding when applying the recyclerview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First learn about socket programing , how to make a p2p connection, how to send data from  server to host and host to server. 
You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36640944/how-to-send-receive-text-between-android-and-computer/36641589#36641589) answer . It will help you.

Comment: Follow the link and try by your own @ExceptionLover